# bioinformatics /genomics

Tags: genetics, bioinformatics, genomics, protein-expression, literature

i am looking for likely truncation sites to prove recombination in sequences. i have 4 sequences. i believe one to be the "real sequence" and the other 3 to be recombinants caused by cleavage possibly due to Arg c proteinase. I know my sequences overlap due to multiple alignments i have performed using UniProt and i have chosen the enzyme due to carrying out cuts on Expasy cutter. If anyone could point me in the right direction this would be much appreciated.
many thanks in advance

Comment: -1 question not currently legible and not clear what you are struggling with. edit the question to make it readable and make the question itself clearer.

Comment: thank you i have rephrased the question, i am new to this site i am looking for truncation sites in sequences if you have any information on useful literature it would be greatly appreciated.many thanks

Comment: Can you please make this a redable post? Posting a ton of sequences seems not helpful to me at leat unless you re-phrase your question. These are protein sequences, so you will not find any stop codons.

Comment: i have specified i am not looking for stop codons but truncation sites the sequences are the ones i am comparing, i am sorry they are not readable as i cannot paste them "in frame".....if you could please direct me towards literature on identifying truncation sites as i believe these sequences to be recombinants of each other due to the alignments i have performed. many thanks

Comment: Truncation sites of what? Proteins? Protein translation? Transcription?

Comment: my professor said pro peptides.....i believe the 3 of these sequences are recombinations of 1 main sequence i retrieved from UniProt

Comment: Then I would recommend using a sequence alignment tool (clustalw should do it) and align the sequences to find out if there are similarities.

Comment: i have done this and i have the alignments which shows there are overlaps...i just don't know what to say to prove my observation beyond what i can see....so i was told to look for "likely truncation sites" to back up my observation, hence my post do you possibly have any recommendations of what direction i should be looking in? many thanks

Comment: using the "preformatted text" option on the alignment text would help to make it much more readable. And RE your comment on you other post - I am being helpful so there is no need for rude comments, properly written and clear questions get better answers, this is how things are done on the SE sites.

Comment: thank you with regards to the pre formatted text option, and it was not a rude comment i am new to the website and everyone has been extremely helpful however if you read the post you would see it is not a duplicate question and an unnecessary response since i am new and trying to navigate my way around the site. many thanks

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1997/biology this would be agood place to get that sort of help

Comment: thank you, do you know anything on sequence recombination due to cleavage and/or truncations?

Answer (score 2):

The sequences you have posted seem to be (protein) amino acid sequences. The stop codon are present in DNA sequences and in mRNA sequences.

In DNA, the bases are A, G, C and T; stop codons are TAG, TGA and TAA.
In RNA, the bases are A, G, C and U; stop codons are UAG, UGA and UAA.
In DNA and RNA, other letters are used to specify degeneracy.

What you have here looks like protein sequences. So, there are no stop codons in sequences you have posted.

Comment: thank you this is correct i meant to say i was looking for truncation sites not stop codons.